# SQL Execute Statement

Tags: php, sql, ajax, execute

I am trying to insert a row to a dynamic HTML table and then update it in a database. I have a SQL prepare and execute statement inside php tags in a separate file. Is there a way that I can put variables inside the execute statement that will read and store information from what was inserted in the dialog box on the main page so that it will insert whatever is typed into the textfields to add a row?? The only thing I can find online so far is hardcoding specific information into the execute statement, which I do not want.

Buttons for table:

```
<form> 
    Table Name: <input type="text" value="Stage_Rebate_Master" id="tableNameInput">
    <button class="create-user" id="insertButton">Insert Test Object</button>
    <button id="updateButton">Update Test Object</button>
    <button id="deleteButton">Delete Test Object</button>
    </form>
```

HTML table that loops through DB to import rows of info:

```
<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">  
<table id="html_master" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
<thead>
    <tr class="ui-widget-header">
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
    <td>Buyer ID</td>
    <td>POC Name</td>
    <td>POC Email</td>
    <td>POC Phone</td>
    <td>Edit/Delete</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>


<?php
    /* Foreach loop that brings in information to populate table */
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="mr_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" name="field" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td class="poc_e" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit">
        <input type="button" class="deactivate" name="deactivate" value="Deactivate"></td>
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
```

DB connection and execute statement:

```
<?php

  $tableName = $_POST['tableName'];

  $host="xxxx"; 
  $dbName="xxxxxx"; 
  $dbUser="xxxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbPass="xxxxxx";

  $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$host.";Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$tableName." (MR_ID, MR_Name, Buyer_ID, MR_POC_N, MR_POC_E, MR_POC_P) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $result = $stmt->execute(array(0,'Test Object', '1234', 'John','john@example.com','555-555-5555'));  
  echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Dialog Box that I want information pulled from and entered into my execute statement:

```
  <p>All form fields are required.</p>

  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="mr_name">Vendor</label>
      <input type="text" id="mr_name">
      <label for="buyer_id">Buyer ID</label>
      <input type="text" id="buyer_id">
      <label for="poc_n">POC Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="poc_n">
      <label for="poc_p">POC Email</label>
      <input type="text" id="poc_e">
      <label for="poc_p">POC Phone</label>
      <input type="text" id="poc_p">

      <input type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Could you maybe [edit] it and add an example?

Comment: @Chris I edited it and added some code to make it a bit more clear

Comment: Could this be taken off hold now!? I updated it and it is clearer now!

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're asking, but maybe you should read up about AJAX?

Comment: I have multiple times...the only thing i can find is hardcoding information into my execute statement...I want whatever is entered in the dialog box on main page to be inserted into my execute statement.

Comment: Please clean up your codes to make them clearer: remove the irrelevant HTML and possibly reduce the form to *one* field. Then indicate the code's expected behavior and its actual behavior.

Comment: @BryanH That HTML is necessary though...that is the dialog box that needs to have the information put into the execute statement

Comment: Nowhere in your codes are the `DIV` or `P` tags used. Nowhere in your codes does the element class names/styles get used. Nowhere in your codes do the comments get used. _You need to remove anything that has nothing to do with the problem you are trying to solve._

Comment: General question: when one submits a [regular HTML form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form), what does the browser do, and how does it know to do that? (hint: your code doesn't do it)

Comment: Okay I edited it...it refreshes? stores the data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128195/discussion-between-bryanh-and-rataiczak24).

Answer (score 0):

An option could be using AJAX to call your code within your separate PHP file and use AJAX to also add a row into your table, or get it to reload the page after you've completed the SQL query.

You can always pass variables through to the PHP page being called through the 'data:' section of the ajax;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addRow() {
ajaxWrite = $.ajax({
    url: './requesters/addRow.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: { fileName: "." + propFolder + currentUser + userTimings,
            fileContents: JSON.stringify( slotTimings )
    },
    beforeSend: function( xhr, settings ) {
        $( "#fileLoadIndicator" ).fadeIn( 0, "linear" );
        document.getElementById( "fileLoadIndicator" ).innerHTML = "Creating custom user file for: " + currentUser + "<br>Now uploading file to server.";
    },
    success: function( data, textStatus, xhr ) {
        document.getElementById( "fileLoadIndicator" ).innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        $( "#fileLoadIndicator" ).delay( 5000 ).fadeOut( "slow", "linear" );
    },
    error: function( xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        document.getElementById( "fileLoadIndicator" ).innerHTML = "No custom user file was able to be written for: " + currentUser + "<br>Error: " + errorThrown + ".";
        $( "#fileLoadIndicator" ).delay( 5000 ).fadeOut( "slow", "linear" );
    }
});
```

}

In the HTML;

```
<button id="addRow" onclick="addRow()">Add a Row</button>
```

To pull them out, its a simple PHP variable assignment;

```
<?php
$fileName=$_GET[ 'fileName' ];
$fileContents=$_GET[ 'fileContents' ];
?>
```